# Why are buttons in Angular getting smaller when using the *ngIf directive?

Tags: angular

So heres the situation.
I have 5 buttons on a sidebar. Only 4 appear at a time, the one that corresponds to the page you are currently at is not displayed.

The five buttons are: Homepage, Trainers, Contact, Timetable and Camps

All the routes these buttons navigate to are child paths of the mainpage.
When the homepage is selected, all the buttons lose a bit of their width, and upon selecting any other component the buttons are with their normal width. 
This only happens if the *ngIfs that control which buttons are displayed are in place. If I remove the *ngIf from the homepage's line, all the buttons always have their normal size no matter the route, if the ngIf is there, the buttonsizes change.

the mainpage html:

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <button *ngIf="selectedPage!='homepage'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-5 py-4 px-5" (click)="navToHomePage()">
          Homepage
        </button>
        <button *ngIf="selectedPage!='timetable'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-5 py-4 px-5" (click)="navToTimetable()">
          Timetable
        </button>
        <button *ngIf="selectedPage!='camps'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-5 py-4 px-5" (click)="navToCamps()">
          Camps
        </button>
        <button *ngIf="selectedPage!='trainers'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-5 py-4 px-5" (click)="navToTrainers()">
          Trainers
        </button>
        <button *ngIf="selectedPage!='contact'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-5 py-4 px-5" (click)="navToContact()">
          Contact
        </button>
      </div>
```

The navigation methods in the mainpage ts:

```
navToHomePage(){
    this.selectedPage = "homepage";
    this.router.navigate(["homepage"], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }

  navToTimetable() {
    this.selectedPage = "timetable";
    this.router.navigate(['timetable'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }

  navToCamps() {
    this.selectedPage = "camps";
    this.router.navigate(['camps'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }

  navToTrainers() {
    this.selectedPage = "trainers";
    this.router.navigate(['trainers'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }

  navToContact() {
    this.selectedPage = "contact";
    this.router.navigate(['contact'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```

In the router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/mainpage/camps", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "mainpage", component: MainPageComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'homepage', component: HomePageComponent },
      { path: 'timetable', component: TimetableComponent },
      { path: 'camps', component: CampsComponent },
      { path: 'trainers', component: TrainersComponent },
      { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

All of the other components that are being displayed by pressing the buttons are identical newly created components with no css and no logic, they just have their own name in the html in a `<p>` tag.

If the ngIf is there, the buttons when I'm on `/mainpage/homepage` look like this:

[image: messed up buttons]

If another button is selected, for example the one that leads to `/mainpage/contact`:

[image: normal buttons1]

If the ngIf is not there for homepage, the buttons have normal width:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-5 py-4 px-5" (click)="navToHomePage()">
  Homepage
</button>
<button *ngIf="selectedPage!='timetable'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-5 py-4 px-5" (click)="navToTimetable()">
  Timetable
</button>
<button *ngIf="selectedPage!='camps'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-5 py-4 px-5" (click)="navToCamps()">
  Camps
</button>
<button *ngIf="selectedPage!='trainers'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-5 py-4 px-5" (click)="navToTrainers()">
  Trainers
</button>
<button *ngIf="selectedPage!='contact'" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg mt-5 py-4 px-5" (click)="navToContact()">
  Contact
</button>
```

like so:
[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because of text length. As far as the post goes whenever the homepage is present they have complete width. As you are using flex, the maximum width button is dictating the width of other buttons, so the homebutton is creating maximum width. To avoid this you can set constant width to all buttons.

Comment: that was it... thank you. 

I assumed that the bootstrap classes set a fix width to the buttons and didn't even think of anything like this. 

I am forever in your debt

Comment: Thanks @rayaqin for your nice words.